Распределение суммы значений на основе исторчиских данных
Необходимо распределить случайное количество гостей на временные промежутки на основе исторических данных. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы excel сам посчитал какой процент от общей суммы гостей приходиться на временной период и распределил новое случайное число в соответствии с старыми данными в столбце Понедельник-тест.
Пример:

Посмотрел способы решения данного вопроса через сводную таблицу или через ввод ручных процентов для каждого временного периода. Может быть есть специальный инструмент для решения этой задачи?

Ну что-то типа в ячейку C2 поместить =B2*C17/B17. Ну и ещё округлить, не знаю как в экселе это. Ну и протянуть ячейку вниз. Только боюсь он не догадается, что у B17 номер не нужно сдвигать в формуле. Ой, только я не понял Итого это что, там явно меньше, чем сумма ячеек по вертикали.

Может быть есть специальный инструмент для решения этой задачи? Угу. Пропорция называется. В школе проходят. А после школы ещё добавляется подзадача "раскидать единицы, оставшиеся после округления" - и вот эту задачу в экселе, да ещё и формулами, лучше даже не пытаться решать... PS. А ещё - что у вас в строке Итого? ну уж точно не сумма...

И чего? Ответ-то нужен или как?

Всё решается одной формулой, а поскольку итого - не того, пусть "1000/396" будет просто коэффициентом пропорциональности:

[C2]=ROUND(B2:B16*C17/B17;0)

Если пересчитать итог,
то можно рассчитать распределение посетителей по интервалам для заданного общего количества:

[C2]=LET(arr;B2:B16;tgt;B18;rs;ROWS(arr);rwv;arr*tgt/SUM(arr);rdv;ROUND(rwv;0);
  dt;SUM(rdv)-tgt;darr;rdv-rwv;cso;SORTBY(SEQUENCE(rs);darr);rdvs;SORTBY(rdv;darr);
  SORTBY(MAKEARRAY(rs;1;LAMBDA(r;c;INDEX(rdvs;r)-IFS(r>rs-dt;1;r<=-dt;-1;TRUE;0)));cso)
)

На иллюстрации, помимо данных автора вопроса, приведён ещё один пример в колонках "F:I". Колонки "Без коррекции" (соответствует rdv из формулы) и выделение жёлтым иллюстрируют работу алгоритма коррекции ошибок округления, который изменяет на 1 количество посетителей в интервалах с наибольшими ошибками округления для устранения разницы с заданным количеством.

"раскидать единицы, оставшиеся после округления"?

Расхождения могут быть и в 2, и в 3, и одну, и в другую сторону (998, 1001). А так как при округлении нарушается точность подбора каждого отдельного числа, то заморачиваться со скурпулезным подбором - гора рождает муху... Достаточно зашить корректировку в одно-два последних значения.  Если же этого все же мало и хочется точности - просим помощи у VBA. Хотя, при округлениях "точной точности" не добиться никакими приемами, нужно ставить ограничения.

Только из спортивного интереса :) Практически - округление уже вносит неисправимую ошибку.

@vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA В данном случае округление не является ошибкой, так как по условию числа должны быть целые (так как являются количеством неделимых объектов).

Я о той ошибке, которая не позволит разделить заданное число на целые числа при условии сохранения долей (% от суммы)

И чего, как дела?

Поиграемся :)
Формула для корректировки (в столбце F), без оптимизации:
{=ЕСЛИ(E2-СУММ(ОКРУГЛ(B6:B20*F2;))=0;
       ОКРУГЛ(B6:B20*F2;);
       ОКРУГЛ(B6:B20*F2;)+
           ЕСЛИ(B6:B20*F2-ОКРУГЛ(B6:B20*F2;)>=
                 НАИБОЛЬШИЙ(B6:B20*F2-ОКРУГЛ(B6:B20*F2;);ABS(E2-СУММ(ОКРУГЛ(B6:B20*F2;))));
               ЗНАК(E2-СУММ(ОКРУГЛ(B6:B20*F2;)))))}

Обнаруженный недостаток: при наличии в исходном диапазоне одинаковых значений НАИБОЛЬШИЙ определит, что корректировать надо больше, чем нужно. Устранить - менять вычисление количества корректировок...

Это все о том, что да, можно поиздеваться, но для данной практической задачи - излишество.
